# Add visual to Custom UI Object

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I have a Custom UIElement I created below.

```
class ClickItem : UIElement
{
    public ClickItem()
    {

    }

    public ClickItem(Color color)
    {
        this.Color = color;
        Ellipse _e = new Ellipse();
        _e.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(this.Color);
        _e.StrokeThickness = 1;
        _e.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
        _e.Width = 10;
        _e.Height = 10;
        this.Plotter = _e;
    }

    public Point CenterPoint { get; set; }
    public Ellipse Plotter { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
}
```

How do I make the `Plotter` Ellipse the visual for the UIElement so when I add a `ClickItem` to a canvas, the `Plotter' shows up.

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
ClickItem clickItem = new ClickItem(Colors.Red);
canvas.Add(clickItem);
```

I can do this but I don't know how to get the `ClickItem` from this if I click on it.

```
canvas.Add(clickItem.Plotter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should inherit from user control, or some other relevant lower class, and add the ellipse as a child of your ClickItem.

Comment: Well that just make too much sence. Time to take a break, I've been working too long and this was too simple. Thanks